# Can I test life cycle methods of Activities and Fragments separately?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-espresso, android-testing

I am testing an Android App with the following libraries:

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
```

I would like to now if I somehow can separately test `onCreate()`-, `onStart()`- and `onResume()`-methods. So is it possible to call one of these methods without calling the others within a certain test case?

Why do I want to do that? In my `Activity` I create a `Fragment` in `onCreate()` and apply it to the `Activity`. But in `onResume()` within the Fragment I setup something which causes the replacement of the `Fragment`attached to the `Activity` by another `Fragment`. And I want to test if the first fragment is loaded. But in my test case `onResume()`is already fired and the first fragment is replaced. So that's why I want to test `onCreate()`separately.

Comment: what do you want to test in `onCreate` or other methods?

Comment: @mallaudin I've just updated my post

Answer (score -2):

```
package com.example.activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Method" , "On Create");


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.e("Method" , "On start");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.e("Method" , "On restart");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("Method" , "On resume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("Method" , "On pause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e("Method" , "On stop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Method" , "On destroy");
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about the activity lifecycle. I don't want to know the name of the methods but how I can start an activity from an `ActivityTestRule`, calling only `onCreate()` but not the rest of the methods.